# PHP to echo multiple results in one line. Merging Foreach/Switch

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I'm trying to echo 3 information in one line and for possible multiple lines. All these 3 information are arrived from either different arrays or overlapping arrays.

> The ultimate desired result :
>
> Pet1(if any) Attrib1(if any) Attrib2 (if any)
>
> Pet2(if any) Attrib1(if any) Attrib2 (if any)
>
> Pet3(if any) Attrib1(if any) Attrib2 (if any)

The complication happens as a result of the position where the Pets, Attrib1 and Attrib2 are highly variable and dependent on the user's input. Any of them may appear or null altogether.

I managed to use a Switch to pull Pet and Attrib1 together. But to echo also the Attrib2, should i use another Switch (Block 2 below). And how do i merge all of them together in one row and one column (ie Pet Attrib1 Attrib2)?

```
// This specifies which row it should display
// Each of the following $xxxRow contains information about the Row position in another array
// Didn't include the Row array here to simplify my question

$Display_Position = array (
'Crocs' => $CrocsRow, 'Cat' => $CatRow, 'Rhino' => $RhinoRow, 'Wolf' => $WolfRow, 'Hyena' => $HyenaRow, 'Lion' => $LionRow, 'Tiger' => $TigerRow, 'Dingo' => $DingoRow, 'Bear' => $BearRow);

 // ------------------   

$Assign_Attributes = array (

'US'=> 
    array ('Wolf'=>'Strong', 'Dingo'=>'Healthy', 'Tiger'=>'Fast', 'Cat'=>'Timid'),

'Africa'=> 
array ('Tiger'=>'Strong', 'Hyena'=>'Healthy', 'Crocs'=>'Fast', 'Rhino'=>'Timid'),

'Asia'=> 
array ('Cat'=>'Strong', 'Wolf'=>'Healthy', 'Crocs'=>'Fast', 'Hynena'=>'Timid'),

'Ocenia'=> 
array ('Bear'=>'Strong', 'Crocs'=>'Healthy', 'Cat'=>'Fast', 'Dingo'=>'Timid'),

);

// ------------------

$colA    // to display column position, comes from another array and not included here
$rowA   // to display row position, comes from another array and not included here

 // ------------------

// BLOCK 1: $_Pets with its assigned attributes
// Success. Managed to display $_Pets with the $Assign_Attributes
// This will display either "Tiger (if any)" or "Tiger (if any) Strong (if any)" in the same row/column 

foreach ($Display_Position as $_Pets => $_PetsLoc){
    if ($_PetsLoc = $rowA) {
        $Attrib = $Assign_Attributes ['Africa'][$_Pets]; // Africa is an eg. It actually is $colA

        switch ($Attrib) {
            case 'Strong':
                echo $_Pets.'Strong<br/ >';         break;
            case 'Healthy':
                echo $_Pets.'Healthy<br/ >';            break;

            case 'Fast':
                echo $_Pets.'Fast<br/ >';           break;

            case 'Timid':
                echo $_Pets.'Timid<br/ >';          break;

            default:
                echo $_Pets.'<br/ >';
            break;      
        }
    }
}

 // ------------------

// BLOCK 2: Attributes 2
// Block 2 should desirable be merged with BLOCK 1. 
// Example: This will eventually display either "Tiger (if any)" or "Tiger Timid (if any)"
// Right now, i'm using CSS to work around for the display of Block 2, which is messy

foreach ($Display_Position as $_Pets => $_PetsLoc){
    if ($_PetsLoc = $rowA) {
        $Attrib2 = $Assign_Attributes ['Africa'][$_Pets];  // Africa is an eg. It actually is $colA
        switch ($Attrib2) {
            case 'Strong':
                echo 'Strong2<br/ >';break;
            case 'Healthy':
                echo 'Healthy2<br/ >';break;
            case 'Fast':
                echo 'Fast2<br/ >';break;
            case 'Timid':
                echo 'Timid2<br/ >';break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this too complicated? It is absolutely too challenging for my level. Is there other PHP tricks to do better job when there's more than one Switch?

Comment: Did you really want to assign `$_PetsLoc` to `$rowA` in if condition?

Comment: You mean the output should display something like eg:"Crocs Strong Healthy"?

Comment: @MahavirMunot That's right. It can also be Crocs Strong Strong2 or Crocs empty empty or nothing displayed at all empty empty empty

Comment: @Mike can you add the $colA,$rowA array

Comment: @MahavirMunot Can do that. But $colA and $rowA actually read from arrays to another and another... wont it be messy if i include all of them here?

Comment: @Spell Yes I do actually. Because ultimately the display position is all influenced by both of them.

Comment: Oops... Deleted my answer because @Spell already posted it as a comment. :/ my bad.

Comment: @jerdiggity You found an answer?

Comment: @Mike I think what @Spell was saying was that when you do that, whatever value was inside `$_PetsLoc` before will now be (essentially) gone. Or reset, rather. e.g. `if ($_PetsLoc = $rowA) {` means "unset the value held by `$_PetsLoc` and assign it a value of `$rowA`. If this is `TRUE` (which it always will be, unless `$rowA` has a value of `0` or `false`), then do the stuff below".

Comment: @Mike well there are lots of answers... Mine wasn't too in-depth but it should definitely help. I'll try to undelete it and if it doesn't help at all, no worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. You may modify it as per your use:

```
<?php

   //$Display_Position1 = array ('Crocs' => $CrocsRow, 'Cat' => $CatRow, 'Rhino' => $RhinoRow, 'Wolf' => $WolfRow, 'Hyena' => $HyenaRow, 'Lion' => $LionRow, 'Tiger' => $TigerRow, 'Dingo' => $DingoRow, 'Bear' => $BearRow);
     $Display_Position = array ('Crocs' => 'CrocsRow', 'Cat' => 'CatRow', 'Rhino' => 'RhinoRow', 'Wolf' => 'WolfRow', 'Hyena' => 'HyenaRow', 'Lion' => 'LionRow', 'Tiger' => 'TigerRow', 'Dingo' => 'DingoRow', 'Bear' => 'BearRow');


     $Assign_Attributes = array (
            'US'=>array ('Wolf'=>'Strong', 'Dingo'=>'Healthy', 'Tiger'=>'Fast', 'Cat'=>'Timid'),
            'Africa'=>array ('Tiger'=>'Strong', 'Hyena'=>'Healthy', 'Crocs'=>'Fast', 'Rhino'=>'Timid'),
            'Asia'=>array ('Cat'=>'Strong', 'Wolf'=>'Healthy', 'Crocs'=>'Fast', 'Hynena'=>'Timid'),
            'Ocenia'=>array ('Bear'=>'Strong', 'Crocs'=>'Healthy', 'Cat'=>'Fast', 'Dingo'=>'Timid'),
           );

     $colA  = 'Africa';  // to display column position, comes from another array and not included here
     $rowA  = 'CrocsRow';// to display row position, comes from another array and not included here


     foreach ($Display_Position as $_Pets => $_PetsLoc){    
       if ($_PetsLoc == $rowA) {
           echo $_Pets;
           //Attrib1
           array_key_exists($_Pets,$Assign_Attributes [$colA])?print('&nbsp;'.$Assign_Attributes ['Africa'][$_Pets]):print('&nbsp;blank'); // Africa is an eg. It actually is $colA
           //Attrib2        
           array_key_exists($_Pets,$Assign_Attributes [$colA])?print('&nbsp;'.$Assign_Attributes ['Africa'][$_Pets]):print('&nbsp;blank'); // Africa is an eg. It actually is $colA             
       }
       else{
           echo "<br />blank";
           //Attrib1
           array_key_exists($_Pets,$Assign_Attributes [$colA])?print('&nbsp;'.$Assign_Attributes ['Africa'][$_Pets]):print('&nbsp;blank'); // Africa is an eg. It actually is $colA        
           //Attrib2
           array_key_exists($_Pets,$Assign_Attributes [$colA])?print('&nbsp;'.$Assign_Attributes ['Africa'][$_Pets]):print('&nbsp;blank'); // Africa is an eg. It actually is $colA
       }
       echo "<br/>";    
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to change this:

```
if ($_PetsLoc = $rowA) {
```

to this:

```
if ($_PetsLoc == $rowA) {
```

Basically each time the loop is running, you're reassigning the variable as if it didn't exist before.

Comment: Thanks and Noted. It actually was a "==" in my code. The code goes far more lines and arrays. The $rowA is also a simplified representation. It pulls data from arrays and then arrays and few modulus to arrive at that. I'm not sure if there's a better way to articulate this. Possible to combine Block 1 and Block 2 togher?